# bind Checkbox value with textbox MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datagridview

I Want to make a table with 2 columns :- first one contains a checkboxes, second one will contain textboxes .
I want to bind the selected checkbox with its textbox and get its value in controller in mvc.

Comment: Are you comfortable enough in razor to come up with a first shot at this little task yourself? It's fine if it doesn't work completely yet. Few people like writing complete answers from scratch, so you may not get a lot of help with such an open question.

Comment: Are you referring to asp.net-mvc? You need to tag you questions correctly, but this is far to broad and unclear, and will likely be closed.

Answer (score -1):

You should store two collections in your viewmodel. For example:

```
    public IEnumerable<bool> CheckBoxes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> TextBoxes { get; set; }
    public int RowsCount { get; set; }
```

If you want to use MVC binding you should name cells in table correctly. You can create your view in this way:

```
    <table>
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.RowsCount; i++)
    {
    <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="CheckBoxes[" + i + "]"    name="Checkboxes[" + i + "]"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="TextBoxes[" + i + "]" name="CheckBoxes[" + i + "]"/></td>
    </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

MVC binding uses name property so you can change your id if don't want to have identical id and name :)

Next, in your controller just create post method with your model as parameter. After submit form, collections in viewmodel should be binded correctly.

Comment: And when this posts back, if any checkboxes are unchecked, binding will fail